# Set a default UI across all components in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sass, compass-sass

Within Sencha Touch, is it possible to define a default UI , like "light" or "dark", that applies to all components (unless overwritten explicitly)?

The aim is to avoid having to declare `ui: "dark"`, or any custom UI that is made, for every element.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Ext.apply(Ext.Component.prototype, {
    getUi: function() {
        var defaultUi = 'light';
        // value of [this.config.ui] is ignored here
        // we can use something like forcedUi
        return (this.forcedUi) ? this.forcedUi : defaultUi;
    }
})
```

The disadvantage of this code is that we need to specify another variable for applying ui different from 'light' (because variable 'ui' via getUi() will always return 'light'):

```
...
items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    forcedUi: 'dark'
}]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am stuck on Touch 1.1 so sunsay's solution didn't work for me, but this did:

```
Ext.CustomToolbar = Ext.extend(Ext.Toolbar, 
{
    ui:'app'
});
Ext.reg('toolbar', Ext.CustomToolbar);
```

So, it's still component-by-component-type, but not component-by-component-instance.  And since you can overwrite the "reg", no need for custom x-types all over the place, either.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know about sencha touch styles and themes. Otherwise you can download a pdf file from this link which clearly describes about how to do it...

http://f.cl.ly/items/d9df79f57b67e6e876c6/SenchaTouchThemes.pdf

In it they are mentioning about scss file where you can specify the base-color, ie

**$base-color: #4bb8f0 ;
$base-gradient: 'glossy';**

Then run it ... you can see the toolbars and buttons created with the color and gradient you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already gone through that. What I mean is, throughout the code are elements with `class` attributes like `x-carousel-dark`. Seems every element is `dark`. I was hoping to replace that with my own.